# Why is my servlet mapping preventing CSS/HTML link?

Tags: html, css, servlets, intellij-14, servlet-mapping

I've been having trouble getting CSS or images to link to my HTML index.jsp page. I created a new project to make sure it wasn't just my computer and CSS/Images worked just fine. Thought maybe I made a mistake when creating the original Project, so moved all of my files into the new project. Same issue happened again. Deleted servlets and pages one by one, restarting the server each time, but nothing worked until I deleted the servlet naming and mapping tags from my web.xml file. Anybody know a workaround for this? I don't even know how/if I could make my web application without servlets. Thank you

Comment: This will indeed happen when you map the servlet on `/` and hereby thus completely override the default servlet.

Comment: THANK YOU. This fixed it. Mapped home servlet on "/", once I switched to "/HomeServlet" everything was fixed.